# crear json y añadir un nuevo objeto

Tags: javascript, html, json

quiero tener un json y de este ir añadiendo objetos. los objetos nuevos los pongo así:

```html
   newUser={
      id_sala:idsala,
      datossala: {
      fecha:fecha,
      nombre:nombre,
      correo:email,
          }
       };
       console.log(newUser)
var jsonnuevousuario = JSON.stringify(newUser);
console.log(jsonnuevousuario)
```

por ahora eso funciona, el tema es como puedo crear una variable que tenga el json para que al añadir el primer usuario ya esté el json creado(la idea es almacenarlo en un localstorage) y una vez hecho eso, como puedo añadir a ese json (con todos los usuarios) añadir un nuevo usuario, es decir al jsonfinal añadir el jsonnuevousuario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En mi opinión, no necesitas tener una *variable* que tenga el JSON.

Veamos primero un ejemplo funcional, el código tienen comentarios para ayudarte a entenderlo:

```js
//variable tipo array para almacenar usuarios
let users = [];
//nuevo usuario declarado con constantes
let newUser = {
  id_sala: "sala17",
  datossala: {
    fecha:'2017-06-01T06:00:00.000Z',
    nombre:"Juan Pérez",
    correo:"juan@perez.com",
  }
};
//agregamos usuarios al arreglo
users.push(newUser);
users.push(createUser("sala18", new Date(2021,6,1), "José Gómez", "jose@gomez.com"));
//ejemplo de cómo serializar el arreglo de usuarios
let jsonusers = JSON.stringify(users);

//ejemplo de cómo deserializar el arreglo, en este caso uso una nueva variable, 
//solo para que quede claro que viene del dato _almacenado_ en la cadena en la serialización
//del paso anterior
let userscopy = JSON.parse(jsonusers);
//agregamos un nuevo usuario, en este caso, a la nueva variable arreglo que tiene lo susuarios
userscopy.push(createUser("sala19", new Date(2021,6,1), "María Sánchez", "maria@sanchez.com"));
//veamos que tiene esta nueva variable
console.log(userscopy);
//ahora persistamos la nueva variable
jsonusers = JSON.stringify(userscopy);
//finalmente, veamos que tiene la cadena que vamos a almacenar
console.log(jsonusers);

function createUser(AidSala, aFecha, aNombre, aCorreo) {
  let result = {};
  result.id_sala = AidSala;
  result.datossala = {};
  result.datossala.fecha = aFecha;
  result.datossala.nombre = aNombre;
  result.datossala.correo = aCorreo;
  return result;
}
```

Y puedes ejecutarlo aquí mismo en el navegador (clic en el botón *"Ejecutar"*).

Si ves, lo que tiene el código es una *función* para crear el objeto para cada nuevo *usuario*: `createUser`.

Cuando tienes los objetos en un arreglo en memoria, te invito a no pensar en términos de JSON, ya que JSON es el *formato* en el que esos objetos se *persisten* en una cadena de texto, para ser almacenados o *transportados* por la red.

Mientras están en memoria, son objetos, instancias de objetos para ser más precisos. Así que agregamos nuevos usuarios al arreglo, en memoria, y finalmente este arreglo lo podemos *persistir* a una cadena.

Para agregar más objetos, interpretamos esa cadena de nuevo a la estructura en memoria (a través de *parse()*) y es al arreglo al que le agregamos un nuevo usuario. Finalmente podríamos persistir de nuevo dicho arreglo.

Comment: pues tengo que analizarlo en profundidad para quedarme con el "funcionamiento" pero creo que es justo lo que necesitaba, luego, al final del todo ya puedo coger el jsonusers y almacenarlo en un localStorage para que al cargar el html lo primero que haga es tener esa memoria disponible. Gracias!!